# how to bind updated mysql view with JPA ,old view is displaying until app is restarted ? looking for solution

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, view

I am trying to bind mysql view with `jtable`
when every table data is changed, view is not updated until appliation is restarted. 
How to get the updated view with JPA mysql?

Comment: hmmm I wouldn't recommend mysql for desktop, it's more optimized for a server that serves many clients, for desktop I'd use sqlite :)

Comment: relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774884/how-do-i-bind-a-database-table-to-my-jtable-and-use-jtable-to-change-and-add-row

Comment: *How to get the updated view with JPA mysql?*: by fixing your code. But since you didn't post any, we can't tell what you're doing wrong.